# Ensure static variables are initialized before using any static methods?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a monitor class with a static (and optionally `final`) variable called ClockValues. This variable is used by every other static method. However, the ClockValues object comes from an external source. Is there way I can ensure external objects and threads to initialize ClockValues before using any static methods in this class? 
Kind of like a constructor but for static variables.

```
public class SharedData {
    private static final MutexSem   mutex = new MutexSem();
    private static ClockValues  clock;

    //my static "Constructor"
    //but I can't force other objects to call this method before all other methods in this class
    //I understand I could use a flag to signal initilization, but I was looking for a cleaner way
    public static  void initialize(ClockValues c){
        mutex.take();
        clock= c;
        mutex.give();
    }

    public static void doSomething(){
        mutex.take();
        //do something with `clock`
        mutex.give();
    }

//... more methods using `clock` variable


}
```

Comment: If the static variable initialized with an initializer or in a static block, it should be initialized when the class is loaded and initialized. What particular code are you concerned about?

Comment: (And if not, why is it a static variable/method? ;-)

Comment: @TedHopp I understand I could use the static block. But the `ClockValues` variable depends on an external class to pass in the values for `ClockValues`. So it must wait for an external call. @user2864740 It's a static variable because this is a multithreaded program, and we are required to use a static monitor to ensure concurrency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want with static methods. You could probably do something with a singleton pattern:

```
public class SharedData {
    private static final MutexSem  mutex = new MutexSem();
    private static SharedData instance;
    private ClockValues clock;

    public static SharedData getInstance(ClockValues c) {
        mutex.take();
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SharedData(c);
        }
        mutex.give();
        return instance;
    }

    private SharedData(ClockValues c) {
        clock = c;
    }

    public void doSomething() { // NOTE: no longer static
        mutex.take();
        //do something with `clock`
        mutex.give();
    }

    //...
}
```

Unfortunately, that would require every call to `getInstance` to have a `ClockValues` value to pass as an argument. Depending on your architecture, though, this might be a feasible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

the standard pattern to initialize singletons is described in `Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 71`:

```
public class AService {
  private static int init = 0;
  private static class Holder {
    private static final AService theService = new AService(init);
  }

  private AService(int init) {
    System.out.println("AService instance initialized with " + init);
  }

  public static AService instance(int init) {
    AService.init = init;
    return Holder.theService;
  }
}
```

Thus instantiation of the service singleton is delayed until first call to instance (which may took additional arguments etc) and you may perform a more complex instantiation. Depending on your project initialization logic you may split `.instance(init)` into `.getFirstInstance(init)` and `.instance()`, but this is solely up to you.